# C# script to return camera to a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

in Unity I have a camera as a child of a 2D gameobject (to follow it around). There is an IF statement that lets me move the camera ahead by holding down a key. I need a code to return the camera back to the gameobject after I let go. Thank you for the help.

```
public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float panspeed = 30f;
    public float panBorderThickness = 30f;
    public GameObject ship1;
    private Vector3 offset;
    

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("f"))
        {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            if (Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - panBorderThickness)
            {
                pos.y += panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.y <= panBorderThickness)
            {
                pos.y -= panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - panBorderThickness)
            {
                pos.x += panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (Input.mousePosition.x <= panBorderThickness)
            {
                pos.x -= panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            transform.position = pos;
        }
        //something to return the camera back when i let go of F key
    }
}
```

Comment: does this work? https://hastebin.com/takefujisu.hs

Comment: will add as an answer if yeah i just wrote the psuedocode rn don't have an editor

Comment: Well when you let go you need yo use the same process to move it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would want to smoothly move the camera back to its original position so I would probably do it like

```
private void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
    {
        var pos = transform.position;
        if (Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - panBorderThickness)
        {
            pos.y += panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.mousePosition.y <= panBorderThickness)
        {
            pos.y -= panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - panBorderThickness)
        {
            pos.x += panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.mousePosition.x <= panBorderThickness)
        {
            pos.x -= panspeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        transform.position = pos;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ship1.transform.position - ship1.transform.forward * 10, panspeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had some trouble with this. The camera stops following the game object and when i am done moving, it returns to original position (the game object has changed its location by then). I changed the "else" statement to "if key G is pressed" and it pans back nicely when i press G but still back to original location. Anyway we can tie the originalposition to the current, active and moving game object?

Comment: @J3KB0T oh sure I didn't know there was a moving object involved ;) see the edit ... Is the camera a child of the ship1 object?

Comment: yes, i wanted it to follow the object but also have the ability to scout ahead.

Comment: If it is a child you might want to rather operate on the `transform.localPosition` so all you ever change is only the local offset against the parent object.

Comment: I thought the same thing, to add ship1.transform.position, but the code does not recognize this or the "else" part. it just doesn't do anything and i do not understand why.

Comment: @J3KB0T I don't believe that ;) If it is not hitting the `if` block, it has to hit the `else` block .. this is `c#` after all. have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)? Sounds like something else is trying to move the camera as well?

Comment: could be an issue from unity and not the script then.

Comment: No could be that you reference the wrong object in `ship1` .. a user issue not a code or program issue ;)

Comment: so the problem was that somewhere along the way i changed the top code to "private gameobject ship1;" when i changed it to public your code worked, however after finally setting on the target at the end, the screen went gray. It must be the camera goes inside the object.

Comment: ok fixed, transform.position = ship1.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, -10); so camera backs out...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Input.GetKeyUp("f")){
    transform.position = ship1.transform.position;
}
```

Sidenote, you can't assign values to only one component of a vector. You need to reassign the entire vector with the new component or add/subtract to the original vector. Your script should look like

```
if (Input.GetKey("f"))
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    if (Input.mousePosition.y >= Screen.height - panBorderThickness)
    {
        pos += new Vector3(0, panspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
    if (Input.mousePosition.y <= panBorderThickness)
    {
        pos -= new Vector3(0, panspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
    if (Input.mousePosition.x >= Screen.width - panBorderThickness)
    {
        pos += new Vector3(panspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.mousePosition.x <= panBorderThickness)
    {
        pos -= new Vector3(panspeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    transform.position = pos;
}

if(Input.GetKeyUp("f"))
{
    transform.position = GameObjectYouWant.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: "Sidenote, you can't assign values to only one component of a vector." - yes, you can. Vector3 is a mutable struct. The documentation for [`Vector3.x`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html) for instance, shows this feature.

Comment: As I understand the question the camera is supposed to smoothly move back .. not snap immediately

Comment: it is working now, but the camera goes inside the object and screen goes blank. how do you manipulate the x y z values of that?

Comment: ok fixed, all you have to do is add + new Vector3(0, 0, -10) to the ship1.transform.position so camera backs out...

Comment: @J3KB0T Did you mean to accept this answer? I thought you wanted the camera to smoothly move back when the F key was released.

Comment: @Ruzihm I didn't know that! I've always thought you had to reassign the entire vector. That's pretty useful.

Comment: @J3KB0T if you want the camera to be slightly offset from the gameobjects position, you can make a Vector3 called maybe offset than add that to the new position when you snap.